# Is there guarantee that iterator from a collection view would see subsequent modification of original map by doing replace?

Tags: java, iterator

I get no ConcurrentModificationException when I obtain an iterator from a collection view and then modify original map by doing replace -  put(alreadyExistingKey, newValue) or replace method.

I undestand why there is no exception, but **is there *guarantee* that iterator will see such modification?**

[API for Map Interface:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--)

> If the map is **modified** while an **iteration over the collection is in
>   progress** (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the
>   results of the iteration are undefined.

**modified** = *any modification* (API does not make any reservation to the contrary!) => including replace ("non-structural" - no change to the size)

**iteration over the collection is in progress** = after I called iterator() method on respective collection view object.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, "one");
map.put(2, "two");

Collection v = map.values();
Iterator i = v.iterator();

// modify (replace) original map
// when iteration is in progress
map.put(1, "newReplacedVal");  

//ConcurrentModificationException expected, but runs fine!
System.out.println(i.next()); // newReplacedVal successfully printed
```

But this is why there is no ConcurrentModificationException:

**API for TreeMap, HashMap is clear:**

> The iterators returned by the iterator method of the collections
>   returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are
>   fail-fast: **if the map is *structurally* modified** at any time after the
>   iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own
>   remove method, the iterator will throw a
>   ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 0):

You get no exception because key sequence inside the map was not changed. You just changed the contents of one of the nodes - with key 1. If you add or remove a key from the map, the iterator will be invalidated.